# Does the order of aggregation terms influence the query speed in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate-functions, elasticsearch-aggregation

The basic logic of a query can be expressed as

```
select count(*)
from a_table
group by a, b, c
```

Does the order of a, b and c influence the performance of ES? I knew this order matters in MySQL, but does the ES have similar mechanism like MySQL?